# Angular data table adding "tree view"

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I need some help how to modify ng table to add tree functionality- to make additional embedded JSON arrays expandable under the main nodes.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0-rc3-nonmin" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ng-table@*" data-semver="0.3.1" src="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table/0.3.1/ng-table.js"></script>

    <link data-require="ng-table@*" data-semver="0.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table/0.3.1/ng-table.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="main" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">


    <button ng-click="tableParams.sorting({})" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Clear sorting</button>
    <p><strong>Sorting:</strong> {{tableParams.sorting()|json}}

    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
            <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'">
                {{user.name}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Age'" sortable="'age'">
                {{user.age}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

And then code where I want to modify the JSON data source:

```
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable']).
controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $filter, ngTableParams) {
    var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34}];

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10,          // count per page
        sorting: {
            name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
        }
    }, {
        total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            // use build-in angular filter
            var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                                $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) :
                                data;

            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });
});
```

This example is in here: [http://plnkr.co/edit/5SQ2YB?p=info][1]

My Custom JSON would look like:

```
[{
    "name": "Tiancum",
    "age": "43",
    "favoriteCars": [{
        "name": "Audi",
        "engines": [{
            "type": "diesel",
            "size": "big"
        },
        {
            "type": "gas",
            "size": "small"
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "Subaru",
        "engines": [{
            "type": "diesel",
            "size": "big"
        },
        {
            "type": "gas",
            "size": "small"
        }]
    }]
},
{
    "name": "JAcob",
    "age": "54",
    "favoriteCars": [{
        "name": "BMW",
        "engines": [{
            "type": "diesel",
            "size": "big"
        },
        {
            "type": "gas",
            "size": "small"
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "VW",
        "engines": [{
            "type": "diesel",
            "size": "big"
        },
        {
            "type": "gas",
            "size": "small"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

What I am trying to achieve is to make the embedded JSON arrays expandable like in here:
[http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/18/][2]

Any ideas for a quick fix for that ?

Comment: Why not use one of the angular tree modules out there? I use this https://github.com/wix/angular-tree-control

Comment: Because the solution above was already in a form of the grid view with paging as I need so I was looking towards the minimum work to put in because of short time I have for this task.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow arbitrary depth for your tree, you'll need to create some kind of directive that renders your data accordingly. Someone shared this Plunkr in the AngularJS IRC last week, which shows an example of how to recursively generated your template from the provided data via a directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/hhLOmGkNnQj0MrcJgyFi

Hopefully that's a decent starting point. For reference, the basic idea is this:

```
angular.module('test', []).directive('blockAttributeMenu', ['$compile',
  function($compile) {
    var Template = '<ul> <li ng-repeat="attribute in (children | orderBy:\'position\')"> {{ attribute.name }}<block-attribute-menu children="attribute.children"/></li> </ul>';
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        'children': '='
      },
      // replace: true,
      // template: Template
      compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {

          element.append(Template);
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

EDIT:

Well, if you're only requirement for the formatting is indenting nodes slightly and you can guarantee a maximum depth of 3 levels (`body>tr>td`), you can probably get away with something as simple as:

1. Sort your array by `BodyId`, then `TrId`, then `TdId`.
2. Loop through array, appending each element to the DOM as a `<tr>` with `<td>` nodes for each attribute
3. For the ID column, just use a conditional that tests your three alternatives (`TrId == null`, `TdId == null`, `else`) and change the level of indentation accordingly
4. If you want to still support the show/hide functionality, you need to also add something like `ng-show` to all elements that should be hideable, and repeat that on each line; for example, `ng-show="show_body2"` to all elements with `BodyId == 2` except the parent, then add `ng-show="show_body2_tr1"` for the next level down, etc. You finish it off with a simple toggle like `ng-click="!show_body2_tr1"`. Alternatively, you can do the same stuff in just a javascript function that modifies the DOM, but then you wouldn't be learning more Angular would you ;)

Comment: Note that the "show/hide" functionality could be accomplished in the template with good old fashioned ngShow wrapping each child node.

Comment: Thanks for answering  ! In the very last moment I had to change the JSON structure, which is changing the whole approach of tackling this problem... I pasted it under...

Comment: Edited answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    {
        "BodyId": 1,
        "TrId": null,
        "TdId": null,
        "Description": "Text Text"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 2,
        "TrId": null,
        "TdId": null,
        "Description": "Text Text"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 3,
        "TrId": null,
        "TdId": null,
        "Description": "Text Text"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 1,
        "TrId": 1,
        "TdId": null,
        "Description": "Text Text"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 1,
        "TrId": 2,
        "TdId": null,
        "Description": "Text Text"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 2,
        "TrId": 1,
        "TdId": null,
        "Description": "Text Text"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 2,
        "TrId": 2,
        "TdId": null,
        "Description": "Text Text"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 3,
        "TrId": 1,
        "TdId": null,
        "Description": "Text Text"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 3,
        "TrId": 2,
        "TdId": null,
        "Description": "Text Text"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 1,
        "TrId": 1,
        "TdId": 1,
        "Description": "Text Text"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 1,
        "TrId": 1,
        "TdId": 2,
        "Description": "Text Text"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 1,
        "TrId": 2,
        "TdId": "1",     
        "Description": "Text Text"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 2,
        "TrId": 1,
        "TdId": 1,
        "Description": "Text Text"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 2,
        "TrId": 1,
        "TdId": 2,
        "Description": "Text Text"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 2,
        "TrId": 2,
        "TdId": 1,
        "Description": "Text Text"
    },
    {
        "BodyId": 3,
        "TrId": 3,
        "TdId": 1,
        "Description": "Text Text"
    }
]
```

So giving this JSON I am trying to achieve this structure:

[Data Structure](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/394x206q90/903/vphFac.png)

Appreciate all help !